# Trying to deregister a WooCommerce script without success

Tags: overriding, woocommerce

I'm trying to deregister a WooCommerce script called 'add-to-cart-variation' found in the following path :theme-folder/woocommerce/assets/js/frontend.
The idea is to by-pass the default script which controls the 'add-to-cart' button for variable products. By default, the 'add-to-cart' button is visible only when the user/customer has selected the variations available to them in the product page, I'm looking to have this button visible at all times.
I added the code below to the functions.php and added add-to-cart-variation.min.js to the child-theme-folder/woocommerce/assets/js/frontend.

Unfortunately I don't see any change, any suggestions for me?

```
function register_woo_radio_button_scripts () {
  wp_deregister_script('add-to-cart-variation');
  wp_dequeue_script('add-to-cart-variation');
  wp_register_script( 'add-to-cart-variation', plugins_url(     get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'woocommerce/assests/js/frontend/add-to-cart-variation.min.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery'), false, true );

  wp_enqueue_script('add-to-cart-variation');

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_script', 'register_woo_radio_button_scripts' );
```

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me:

```
function wc_deregister_javascript() 
{
    wp_deregister_script( 'wc-add-to-cart-variation' );
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'wc_deregister_javascript', 100 );
```